# Load external element ID into DIV without jQuery's load() function

Tags: jquery

I got some great help on an earlier problem with this project, but now it's gotten even more complicated (for me, at least). This is a Q&A project with a question, four possible answers, and an answer button below that will reveal the answer in a div hidden above the button. I got it working great when the answer was actually in the div, but now I need to try and load the answer from an external HTML file into the now empty div. jQuery's load() function worked great in a browser, however, this project is an enhanced epub file for the iBooks, which apparently does not allow the load() function (it does allow jQuery, though).

Is there an alternative way to load an element ID into the DIV without using load()? Also, how do I get the toggle to close the previous div when opening another div now that this has become more complicated?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".answer").click(function() {
        $(this).prev(".content").load($(this).attr('href')).toggle("slow");
    return false; // And prevent it following the link
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
div.content {
    display: none; /*--hidden by default--*/
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.answer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.92em;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-indent: 0em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 1em 0em 0em 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="keep">
    <p class="q"><samp class="q-no">1.</samp> Interpret the following directions:</p>
    <p class="q-equation">i cap po qid × 10d</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">a.</span> Take one capsule by mouth four times a day for ten days.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">b.</span> Take one capsule by mouth three times a day for ten days.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">c.</span> Take one capsule by mouth twice a day for ten days.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">d.</span> Take one capsule by mouth once a day for ten days.</p>

    <div class="content">
    </div>

    <a class="answer" href="04b-Ch4-Answers.html #anchor-24-anchor">Answer</a>
</div>

<div class="keep">
    <p class="q"><samp class="q-no">2.</samp> Interpret the following directions:</p>
    <p class="q-equation">ii tab po tid × 7d.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">a.</span> Take two tablets by mouth four times a day for seven days.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">b.</span> Take two tablets by mouth three times a day for seven days.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">c.</span> Take two tablets by mouth twice a day for seven days.</p>
    <p class="an"><span class="choice">d.</span> Take two tablets by mouth once a day for seven days.</p>

    <div class="content">
    </div>

    <a class="answer" href="04b-Ch4-Answers.html #anchor-25-anchor">Answer</a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: does any AJAX request work? If not you'll need to use a server-side language.

Comment: I'm not sure if any AJAX request will work in an epub, to be honest. This is the only thing I've tried. And unfortunately, because this is an epub file, a server-side language would not be applicable. Javascript is itself an entirely new thing to ebooks with the EPUB3 standard.

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if you're having a problem with the same-origin-policy.  This prevents you from accessing content via ajax from a site with a different domain than what you're running on.  See this [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for more info.

In a browser like Chrome, you can check the debug console to see if it reports any requests were blocked because of same origin issues.

It makes no sense to me that you could use jQuery, but not `.load()` (which is why I suspect it's a same-origin-policy issue), but if that really is the case, you can write your own mini version of `.load()` by fetching the content with ajax and then putting the result into your div.  FYI, if it is a same origin issue, you won't be able to get around it this way.  You will have to have a server that is on your same domain that you can request data from and it will have to go get data from the other site for you.  Or, you will have to have a cooperating server on another domain that you can use JSONP with.

Comment: I read the MDN reference initially when I had issues testing the file on Chrome, but the problem is that with an epub file all of the files are local. I can't pull the file from a server, so if it is this local hosting issue there's no real way to resolve that.

Comment: Since this is a pretty constraining issue for a local hosted epub file, I'd suggest searching through your epub/iBooks developer doc to see if there is some kind of work-around because it seems like they would want to offer some sort of solution here so you could offer content that allows viewing of dynamic data retrieved from the outside world (wouldn't work while you were offline obviously).

Comment: Apple is not the most helpful when it comes to advising what you can and cannot do in an epub file, unlike app development. The same goes for B&N and especially for Amazon's accursed Fire. They either treat the spec like sacred gnosis or ignore it completely. And the publisher would not like the idea of the content always being available. I appreciate your advice, though.

Comment: I mean "not always being available". Sorry.

Comment: Can you embed an iframe who's source is hosted on your server which has it's own javascript that does ajax from that server?

Comment: I can't host on a server as the epub has to be a self-contained entity that's not relient on wi-fi to function properly, but you have given me an idea for a possible workaround so long as iframes are actually supported in epub files on iBooks. The only problem would be that I would need to place every answer into its own HTML file in order to prevent all of the answers from being scrollable. This isn't the solution to my original problem, but it's a possible workflow alternative. I'll have to mull it over and test it on the iPad. Thanks.